# How do I make make things move properly at angles in Java

Tags: java, trigonometry, shapes, angle

I have a class called Bullet in a sort of birds eye view shooter game. I used to run it simply so that it moved based on an inputted direction, which could only be north south east or west. I now want to make it so you can shoot at any angle, but if I shoot it is inverted on the Y axis (Meaning if I aim Up it goes Down). Here is my code (Yes i did remember to convert to Radians). Each bullet is made of a small line and here is an exerpt from the move method:

```
double scaleX = Math.sin(angle);
double scaleY = Math.cos(angle);
x = x + (MOVE_SPEED * scaleX);
x2 = x2 + (MOVE_SPEED * scaleX);
y = y + (MOVE_SPEED * scaleY);
y2 = y2 + (MOVE_SPEED * scaleY);
```

x, x2, y, and y2 all dictate the points on the line. I only know a bit about Trig so any help would be fantastic. Thanks!

EDIT: I made a mistake earlier in saying it goes right instead of left and vice versa, but  it goes up instead of down and vice-versa, and acts properly left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too obvious to be correct:
Change

```
double scaleY = Math.cos(angle);
```

to

```
double scaleY = -Math.cos(angle);
```

Comment: Ya shortly after i tried that and it worked so i just went with it, thanks!